# React Native Compilation Error : Could not determine the dependencies of null. Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: java, react-native, dependencies, gradle-java-toolchain

As you can see I tried to run my react native project and the following error occured.

`

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'NSS_GECBSP'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> > The new Java toolchain feature cannot be used at the project level in combination with source and/or target compatibility

`

I was debugging the another problems. I installed the gradle and jdk 17, set both in the path of environment variables. Set the gradle in my project.
Then after when I ran the following command this error message appeared.
Expecting that my project would run smoothly but it did not.